# I want to stop a program in my computer

Tags: window

This file has been generated by some program in my TEMP folder. How can I know which program has created this file. I want to stop this program to run in my computer, but I can not find it out.

FXSAPIDebugLogFile

Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=FXSAPIDebugLogFile

Comment: This question isn't really about programming. I think this question should be moved to SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is related to MS program. 
you can read how to clean the file and more about the issues [here](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-12546_102-234539/fxsapidebuglogfile-txt-does-anyone-know-what-this-is/) [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/fxsapidebuglogfile-have-no-clue-to-get-rid-of-it/a5e508dd-7e0e-47f3-80af-0fee50bf0fd4) and [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/50955-temp-file-fxsapidebuglogfile.html)

Some of them are pretty old, since 2007, but are still relevant.
Also next time it could help if you state which windows you have ? XP/Vista/Win7